# Questions about two metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(E,d_1)$ and $(E,d_{2})$ be two metric spaces we assume that for every sequence $x_{n}$ in  $E$ we have :
$x_{n} \rightarrow^{d_{1}} x \Rightarrow x_{n} \rightarrow^{d_{2}} x$ such that $(E,d_1)$ is compact space

1. Prove that F is closed in $(E,d_2)$ iff closed in $(E,d_{1})$
2. show that $(E,d_{2})$ is compact  
   My attempt : 
   $1 )$  let $x\in \overline{F}$ $\implies$ $\exists x_{n}\in F$ such that $x_{n}\rightarrow^{d_{1}} x$ but since F is closed in $(E,d_2)$ so we have $x_{n} \rightarrow^{d_{2}} x \in F$  Hence $\overline F=F$ Conversely the same way . 
   $2 )$ let $V_i$ be a collection of closed subspaces of $(E,d_2)$ such that $\bigcap_{i \in J} V_{i} \neq \varnothing$ since every closed in $(E,d_2)$ is closed in  $(E,d_1)$  so $\bigcap_{i \in J} V_{i} $ is closed in $(E,d_1)$ . by assumption $(E,d_1)$ is compact so $\bigcap_{i \in J} V_{i} $ is compact  in $(E,d_1)$ as a closed subspace in compact space . Hence it has has a finite subcollection with  the intersection is non-empty . we deduce that $(E,d_2)$ is compact.

Comment: you can find the answer in the Kaczor series books in mathematical analysis

Comment: The identity map $(E,d_1)\to(E,d_2)$ is continuous

Comment: @mahdimeisami Which one ?

Comment: Problems in Mathematical Analysis II: Continuity and Differentiation (Student Mathematical Library, Vol. 12) @bapob

Comment: @mahdimeisami Ok thank you !!

Comment: @mahdimeisami sry but i didn't find it in this book

Comment: You need compactness for 1 too

Comment: Your attempt for 1 is unclear: what direction are you proving? closure taken in what space?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  the direction 1 $\implies$ 2

Comment: 1\implies$ 2 is not what you have to show but closed in $d_1$ iff closed in $d_2$ has two implications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $1_E: (E,d_1) \to (E,d_2); 1_E(x)= x$ is continuous as a direct consequence of the convergence condition (using that continuity is sequential continuity in metric spaces). So 2 follows right away as a continuous image of a compact space is compact.
ALso, $1_E$ is a homeomorphism (being bijective and a closed map as the domain is compact) so 1 also follows immediately from properties of homeomorphisms.

A direct proof, not using maps: if $F$ is $d_2$-closed, let $x_n \to_{d_1} x$ where all $x_n \in F$; the condition gives $x_n \to_{d_2} x$ and $F$ being $d_1$-closed gives $x \in F$ and so $F$ is $d_2$-closed. If however $F$ is $d_1$-closed it's $d_1$-compact (being $d_1$-closed in the $d_1$-compact $E$) and so if $x_n \to_{d_2} x$ for all $x_n \in F$ and $x \in  E$ we find a subsequence $x_{n_k} \to_{d_1} x'$ for some $x' \in F$ by $d_1$-compactness (in sequence form) applied to $F$, and the condition gives $x_{n_k} \to_{d_2} x'$ and as limits are unique in metric spaces we get that $x'=x$ and so $x \in F$ and $F$ is $d_2$-closed.
Your proof doesn't use the compactness and is incorrect.

The second of your proofs *does* use a valid idea: by the first fact, $(E,d_1)$ and $E,d_2)$ have the families of closed sets with the FIP. And the former all such families have a common point and so the same holds in $(E,d_2)$ as well.